Which approach is more efficient with hibernate
Let's consider a class Transaction
 @Entity
    public class Transaction {
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Business business;
    
        @Column(name = "business_code")
        private String businessCode;
    
    
    }

which method is more efficient to fetch transactions by business using byBusinessCode which is a column in the table Transaction or using byBusiness so the whole object Business which is a dependency in the class Transaction ?

'efficient' is a nebulous term. What do you mean? I assume 'more performant', i.e. faster or at least using fewer resources? Another thing that one might call 'efficient' is, for example, "less lines of code". You should update your question and make this more clear. But, note that if it's "performance", the answer is pretty much the same answer you get for any 'performance JPA' question: The spec doesn't say and no general answer is possible at all. For your specific situation (so the DB engine you run it on, JDBC driver, etc), there's an answer. You didn't specify those.

(And, also, a more general usual answer to any performance question: Don't worry about it, it does not matter, worrying about performance before there's an issue pretty much always is a very bad idea). Things are faster than you think, the right answer is: "Whatever leads to code that most closely vibes with how you want to program and adheres closely to the thing you are modelling". If there is an actual performance problem, then you worry about it, and as a bonus, you now have actual underperforming code to e.g. run profilers and EXPLAIN against).

There is no conceptual difference between a "column in the table" and a "whole object": The "whole object" is a column in the table, too!
If you look at the actual database schema, we have something like
+-------------+       +-------------+
|Transaction  |       | Business    |
+-------------+       +-------------+
|business_id  |------>| business_id |
|business_code|       | ...         |
+-------------+       +-------------+

if you query by business entity, hibernate will translate this to the SQL query
select ... from Transaction where business_id = ?

and if you query by code, hibernate will translate it to
select ... from Transaction where business_code = ?

As you can see, the SQL is structurally identical. The performance will therefore depend on the usual things, most notably whether there is a suitable index on this field (which hibernate creates automatically for primary and foreign keys, but may need to be manually created for other columns), and to a lesser extent on the datatypes of the fields involved.
(the answer would be different if the relationship were a @OneToOne(mappedBy = ...) the other table. Then, the database schema would look like
+---------------+       +----------------+
|Transaction    |       | Business       |
+---------------+       +----------------+
|transaction_id |<------| transaction_id |
|business_code  |       | business_id    |
+---------------+       +----------------+

and querying a transaction by business would translate to
select ... 
from Business 
left join Transaction on Business.transaction_id = Transaction.transaction_id 
where business_id = ?

and that join would create extra work for the database that might have performance implications. But @ManyToOne can not use mappedBy, so this can not happen in your case.)
BTW, you can easily check what your queries are being translated into by turning on Hibernate's SQL logging. If you are new to hibernate, I recommend doing so to better understand what it does.
